# Installation of R Package "comparedf" failed

Tags: r

I wanted to install the R package `comparedf` with the following simple code:

`install.packages("compareDF")`

The R Output afterwards was:

> ** installing *source* package 'compareDF' ...
>   ** package 'compareDF' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** R
>   ** data
>   *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
>   ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
>   Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>     there is no package called 'rlang'
>   ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'compareDF'
>   * removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/compareDF'
>   In R CMD INSTALL
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     installation of package ‘compareDF’ had non-zero exit status

I already tried then:

- Installing the package manually
- Deleting the folder and try the installation again
- restarting R Studio.

Unfortunately, nothing helped.

I would be happy for some help!

Comment: Welcome to SO. The error message says that the package `rlang` is not installed. Have you tried to install `rlang` and then see if you can install `compareDF`?

Comment: Is there output before this? The dependency tree (including rlang) should be installed automatically.

Comment: Also, on the mirror I'm using, compareDF is available as a Windows binary. Why is your setup installing from source?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! And so sorry for my late response. In fact, your answers were really helpful. I dont know why it didn`t install rlang automatically, but I did it then manually and it worked and I then could also install compareDF. So, thanks a lot!